# Android M HttpClient removal breaks compatibility?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

We know that Android M has removed support for HttpClient. Apps linking with it will have to explicitly say so: add a library dependency in your gradle file.

But does it break backward compatibility with existing applications?
Suppose I wrote an app which supports Api level 1 and higher and it's never maintained since last year. The targetSdkLevel of the app is certainly lower than 22. Will it crash on Android M？  The source code could have been lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer looks to be **yes**.

I looked in the Android M source code through the SDK manager, and the package for the client is not in the source.

**Package name for the HttpClient:**

> org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

**Existing paths:**

> org.apache.http.conn
>
> org.apache.http.params

Comment: Really surprised for the "yes" answer. In my mind Android is so perfect and powerful, especially in terms of the amazing compatibility design.    So I would still want an **official** answer for this.

Comment: The official answer is to use the legacy library as [documented here](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

Answer (score 1):

Ways to fix this:

1. Add this to your build.graddle:

`android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}`

2. Use [OkHttp-UrlConnection](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-urlconnection) as an almost drop in replacement by adding this to your build.graddle:

`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'`

Example usage:

`private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = new OkUrlFactory(okHttpClient).open(url);`